# Are the definitions of convolution here contradict each other?

Tags: convolution

Here are two definitions from a lecture slides file from the internet:

[image]
[image]

It looks strange that the first uses x-u and the second uses x-u+1. Are they both correct? I am confused.

Link to file:
http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/cfcs1/lectures/cfcs_l15.pdf

Comment: The vector definition is probably assuming that indexing starts at $1$ rather than $0$.

Comment: ..., so that the first term $a_1b_1$ gets assigned to $c_1$. Then $a_1b_2+a_2b_1=c_2$ etc.